# How to remove Grand Total and Subtotal in Excel using PyWin32 module?

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, pywin32

I am using PyWin32 module of python to create excel pivot tables. And, the problem is that it is automatically adding the 'Grand Total' and 'Subtotal' fields. Is it possible to hide those fields in the code itself?

TIA!

Comment: You need to show the code you are debugging. Including the XLS file.